# Is it possible to get data from multi databases in Android sqlite? OR any quick way to insert data to database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Is it possible to get data from multi databases in Android `SQLite`?
eg: `SELECT * FROM db1.tableA A, db2.tableB B WHERE A.id=B.id;`

Pleaes help, I cannot find any related in `SQLiteOpenHelper` and `SQLiteDatabase` classes. Thanks

If it is not possible.  Is it any quick way to insert large amount of record to database? I have a XML file with 3000 records. It takes around 3 to 4 mins to insert it (That's way I put the data to db2).

Comment: It seems that SQLiteDatabase can contain one DB only. I have no idea of how to link up two DB in Android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very possible to use multiple databases for a single Android application. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848915/multiple-database-in-single-app-in-android) for a similar question.

If you'd like to avoid using multiple databases, which I would recommend, there have many questions that address speeding up database access times. I would take a look at these resources:

[Inserting 1000000 rows in sqlite3 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733023/inserting-1000000-rows-in-sqlite3-database/10733844#10733844)
Which links to:
http://tech.vg.no/2011/04/04/speeding-up-sqlite-insert-operations/

Basically, use database transactions that surround your entire insert statement (which are described above). This reduces overhead by creating a separate transaction for EACH insert.

Answer (score 11):

You can attach another SQLite DB like this:

```
db.execSQL("attach database ? as userdb", new String[]{"/data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/databases/user.db"});
```

and then use "userdb.table" to access it from your main db.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/u3WYg-0FHZ0

Comment: great men ;) really usefull

Comment: @kolijaTM how can i find 2nd db address that you mentioned here ""/data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/databases/user.db""...

Comment: @AliAnsari: userdb.getPath() https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#getPath()

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to query two different databaes at once with one query, but you must use ATTACH first to put them together.

Documentation for the SQLite ATTACH keyword [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html)

There'a a good example [here](http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/05/29/how-to-attach-multiple-sqlite-databases-together/), although it isn't in java/android code, it shows the SQL commands you would need to do it all.

[This page](http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/readme_sqlite_tutorial.html) also covers it (look about 1/4 of the way down).